# unable to display included data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

i'm fetching data in `JSON API` format with the `Ember Data` and `JSONAPIAdapter` on my `Route` - this is working fine

```
// ok 

/posts/1

this.store.findRecord('posts', params.post_id);
```

i'm now trying to load included data using `ds-finder-include`, the data is getting fetched, but isn't reflecting in the `.hbs`

https://www.emberjs.com/blog/2016/05/03/ember-data-2-5-released.html#toc_code-ds-finder-include-code

```
// not working    

/posts/1/comments

this.store.findRecord('posts', params.post_id, { include: 'comments' });
```

hbs:

```
{{#each post.comments as |comment index|}}
     comment: {{comment}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your comments and code are contradicting. You say in the comments that the data is getting fetched but not being reflected in the templates.

However, in the code, the part that appears to not be failing is fetching the data for the second call: `this.store.findRecord('posts', params.post_id, { include: 'comments' });`

Does a normal GET request for */posts/1/comments* to your backend successfully return data?